# Combining ST_CONTAINS and ST_BUFFER using same table in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, geopackage

I am looking to select some points within a created buffer from other points in the same table.
I would like something like this:

```
Select a.geom , a.type
from a
where st_contains( (st_buffer( (a.geom where a.type = 'b'), 50), (a.geom where a.type = 'c))
```

I do not know how to solve this, and I do not seem to find a reasonable solution that do not include creating a new table for ex.

```
 a.geom where a.type = 'b
```

And that is not really what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may just reference the table twice:

```
Select distinct c.geom , c.type
from a b,a c
where st_contains( (st_buffer( b.geom, 50), c.geom) = 1
and b.type = 'b'
and c.type = 'c'
```